# Matplotlib: 2-D plot changing line color with 3rd dimension (category)

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I change the color of a regular 2-D plot according to a third dimension/category?
For example, suppose we recorded the coolant temperature of a vehicle with time.  We plot that with time on the horizontal axis, and temp on the vertical axis.  We also recorded at each time whether the "high temp indicator light" was on or off.  When the light was on, we want the plotted light to be red; green if the indicator was off.

It's basically a plot of 3-D data where we assign a particular color of line to the third data dimension (z).  I do not want to look at a 3-D plot with 3 axes for this particular application; just a regular 2-D plot changing the line color as appropriate.

Comment: Best thing I can think of is to split up the time series data according to category, and plot each piece in a different color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SciPy.Cookbook.MulticoloredLine`.

Another approach could be - add on/off [ColorBar](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/colorbar_only.html) in the bottom of plot.

Comment: Is `SciPy.Cookbook.MulticoloredLine` a function? I cannot find such a function in Google.  Your answer would be more useful if you explained how to use this function to solve the problem.

Comment: @Dharman Based on the old link, http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/MulticoloredLine, it probably refers to https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Matplotlib_MulticoloredLine.html